# Prolog Infinite Loop: Bi-Directional Predicates

Tags: prolog

I'm using https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ as an online Prolog sandbox, but with the simple code below, where I'm trying to define a bidirectional statement to check if 2 atoms(I think?) share a friend, the program seems to be stuck in an infinite loop. What have I done wrong?

```
friends(lisa, jack).
friends(lisa, jane).

friends(X, Y) :- friends(Y, X).

mutual_friends(X, Y) :- friends(X, Z), friends(Y, Z).
```

When I query `mututal_friends(jack, jane)` I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that your rule can expand infinitely. You should define a `friend_` predicate to define friendships and then `friend(X, Y) :- friend_(X, Y) ; friend_(Y, X).`

Comment: Why add the underscore? Am I defining two completely separate predicates? Just duplicating code? Because I don't like the feel of that.

Comment: @HarithShah you're not duplicating anything, you're just making the bidirectional relationship work without causing infinite deductions

Comment: But I'm right in saying you're defining an under-the-hood```friend_(X, Y)``` predicate and then using the ```friend(X, Y)``` predicate to mask over it and make the bidirectional functionality work, right? Or is an underscored predicate something special and supported in Prolog?...

Comment: @HarithShah indeed